# Importing tex2max.js into an angular project via npm / index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, import

When I try to import `tex2max` using `declare var tex2max: any;` I get a `ReferenceError: tex2max is not defined`. But this doesn't occur with other npm packages. I have tried binding the scripts by installing the npm package and through the script tag in index.html to no avail.

Here is a CDN file of the source code:

https://unpkg.com/tex2max@1.3.0/lib/tex2max.js

Comment: Why don't you just `import TeX2Max from 'tex2max' ` in the file you're using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project author corrected their bundle a little you could do:

```
import TeX2Max from 'tex2max';
```

But that ends in error [EDIT: *on stackblitz*]

```
Error in /turbo_modules/tex2max@1.3.0/lib/tex2max.js (13:28806)
Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '[object Object]'
```

The best option is to file an issue with the author.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-buocoj)

Comment: Don't know why I didn't try this before (I think I did but had another error), but it worked ths time!